# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable SMOTE object - Use for NLP Email Export Classification

Tags: nlp, smote

I am having an issue in using SMOTE in a NLP project I am working on. My output is showing it has a non iterable SMOTE object. By using the untrained Y, it can tell there are multiple rows, so it clearly can see the values aren't null. I tried testing a few ways by vectorizing the Y, using the normal Y train, but I still get the same error. I am unsure on exactly how to get this code to work for SMOTE.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import neural_network 
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

start = time.perf_counter()

df = pd.read_excel(r'F:\Documents\Graduate Research\RMGmail2YrsClassified.xlsx')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print("Lets start by looking at the top of the dataframe.")
print(df.head(10))

print(df.groupby('Classification').describe())
print(type(df['Classification']))

#independent 

#join into 1 column to do analysis - multiple columns do not work
df['Text']= df['Subject'].astype(str)+ ' ' +df['Body'].astype(str)

#1D array required for vectorizer
X = df['Text']

#dependent Y- like multinomial logistic regression with multiple buckets
df['Classification']=df['Classification'].astype(str).str.replace("1","1.Primary")
df['Classification']=df['Classification'].astype(str).str.replace("2","2.Secondary")
df['Classification']=df['Classification'].astype(str).str.replace("3","3.Social")
df['Classification']=df['Classification'].astype(str).str.replace("4","4.Promotional")
df['Classification']=df['Classification'].astype(str).str.replace("5","5.Spam")

y = df['Classification']

print("Lets also check the total number of items in each category.")
print(y.value_counts())


#stratify each category to provide more accurate results
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.3,stratify=df['Classification'], random_state=53)

print(type(y_train))
#x and y
print(X_train.head(5))

#TF-IDF Weighted Vectorizer
v = TfidfVectorizer()
#astype need to covert export file to string for Vectorization
X_train_v = v.fit_transform(X_train.values.ravel().astype('str'))
#X_test_v = v.fit_transform(X_test.values.ravel().astype('str')
y_train_v = v.fit_transform(y_train.values.ravel().astype('str'))


"""
#SMOTE- vectorize first
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='minority')
X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit(X_train_v, y_train_v)

print("check for equal class distribution of minority class:")
print(y_sm.value_counts())
"""
```

If this is not enough information I have included the source code in full along with some sample data that should be sufficient.

https://pennstateoffice365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/rim5532_psu_edu/EsBJms3PE41Evv6HYziKFOQB8yUh6xzon_aQtM7LIKTRiw?e=gbalBp

PW: is 2235

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you converted the target variable `Classification` to a string, this is a mistake because the target class should be represented as an integer. Additionally you applied TFIDF to the column: this doesn't make any sense and probably causes the SMOTE error, because SMOTE expects a regular target variable (integer).

Additionally:

- Resampling is unlikely to work well with text data. You can try with/without SMOTE to check.
- Careful: the commented line `#X_test_v = v.fit_transform(X_test.values.ravel().astype('str')` is wrong, the TFIDF representation of the test set should be obtained only by using `v.transform`.

Comment: So I tried:
df[['Classification']]=df[['Classification']].astype(int)

and 

y = df[['Classification']]

But I get the same error.

Could you explain that 2nd sentence a little more for me about applying TFIDF to a column? The vectorizer works for me outside of smote in its current form.

Also that last bit about ravel, I got rid of that as it was giving me errors but some similar comments around this issue used it so I thought it would help.

Comment: Also for modifying the testing set I will use v.transform ^

Comment: @Rob I meant the line `y_train_v = v.fit_transform(y_train.values.ravel().astype('str'))
` should be removed, the TFIDF encoding makes sense only for text values and never for the target (which should be integer). I think it's this line which causes the SMOTE error but I'm not sure.

Comment: Alright I will try that and get back to you

Comment: Okay so I exclusively ran it 2 ways both with only X_train_v = v.fit_transform(X_train.values.astype('str')). First I tried keeping the Y as an int .astype(int). I also tried leaving it as a string value like 4.Promotional (which works with TF-IDF for my models below). In both situations I only used the vectorized X_train (like I have used for my models below without an issue. Still I get the non-iterable SMOTE object

Comment: I wanted to get back to you and tell you I found a solution, but it wasn't with this code. Using imblearn.pipeline fixed the issue

from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline

textclassifier =Pipeline([
   ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
   ('smote', SMOTE(random_state=12)),
   ('mnb', MultinomialNB())
])

textclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = textclassifier.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

Comment: It's too hard to follow your code this way without the code or the data, and also I don't have time ;) My advice: start by making a classifier work (training then testing with evaluation) in the simplest setting, i.e. without SMOTE. Once you have it fully working, you can reintroduce SMOTE now that the format is correct. In any case, SMOTE is very unlikely to help because text data doesn't work this way. The idea that one should systematically try to 'fix' data imbalance is actually misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Change

```py
#SMOTE- vectorize first
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='minority')
X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit(X_train_v, y_train_v)
```

to

```py
#SMOTE- vectorize first
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy='minority')
X_sm, y_sm = smote.fit_resample(X_train_v, y_train_v)
```

If you take a look at the documentation, if you use the `.fit()` method, the only thing it returns is the fitted object. And method `.fit_resample()` does return the resample values (2 return values).

Let me know if that solves your problem (the code error).